# Laptop hard disk makes loud aggressive revving noise

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

Imagine a 17 year old revving a Ferrari, the hard disk sounds like that for about 5 seconds then returns to a normal noise. The revving noise is  far louder than a traditional disk thrashing under load. The disk doesn't appear to click like a traditional disk failure and the laptop remains operational.

The disk is a 2.5" WD 500Gb and only about 6 months old, to replace a previous dead (clicking) HDD.

What I'd like to know, is if anyone has seen a disk do this before and what it is? Does this mean the disk is dying?

I'll upload a audio clip once I've eaten.

Comment: check your SMART stats, and any vendor disk diagnostics for indications of imminent failure, and plan to replace the disk in the near future. Mechanical disks are quite susceptible to damage when moved about excessively, making laptop hard disks somewhat more prone to failure before their expected expiration date. Let us know what the smart stats indicate. I use SpeedFan in Windows to read SMART info, and palimisest (gnome-disk-utiltiy) in linux.

Comment: are you certain this isn't the cpu fan spinning up and down based on load? Fans get louder over time, especially if, say, a piece of paper got into one of the vent holes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it's (as others have suggested) the CPU fan, it makes a very loud revving sound and then stops spinning.

Will replace once I've ordered a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to run a SMART scan on the disk and see if that is successful.
Go to the cmd prompt and type wmic, then hit enter. Then type diskdrive get status and hit enter. If it fails, that's your issue, but even if it passes it still may be the drive, but it's far less likely. The other cause could be that the heat exhaust fan is making the noise you are describing and not the hard drive. Nevertheless, back up your data ASAP, and complain to WD if the drive breaks. It shouldn't be broken already.

Comment: "It shouldn't be broken already." - assuming it has been handled fairly. A single drop of the laptop may be enough (don't even throw it on top of a bed either), especially if the thing is running.

Comment: @hannu Yes, assuming proper treatment. I like to give the benefit of the doubt. Also, the question author wrote an answer saying that I was right in the second guess that it could be the exhaust fan.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, test it with another computer  / dock. Newer hard disk should never make sounds like that, generally if they make "strange" noises they should be backupped and replaced as soon as possible or data loss may happen.